# core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Class constructor IonSlides cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, swiper.js, ionic6

The following error occurred when creating slide from ionic6 to swiper.

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Class constructor IonSlides cannot be invoked without 'new'
TypeError: Class constructor IonSlides cannot be invoked without 'new'**

I don't know what the problem is.
My code is as follows.

- tab3.page.html

  ````
    <swiper #swiper [config]="config">
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 4</ng-template>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 5</ng-template>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 6t</ng-template>
    </swiper>
  </ion-content>```
  ````
- tab3.page.ts

  ````
  import SwiperCore, {Navigation, Autoplay, Keyboard, Pagination, Scrollbar, Zoom, A11y,EffectFade} from 'swiper';
  SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Autoplay, Keyboard, Pagination, Scrollbar, Zoom ,A11y, EffectFade]);
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-tab3',
    templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss'],
    encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.None
  })
  export class Tab3Page implements AfterContentChecked{
    text: any;
    @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;
    @ViewChild('swiper') swiper:SwiperComponent;
  }```
  ````
- tab3.mojule.ts

  ````
  import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
  import { NgModule , CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
  import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
  import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  import { Tab3Page } from './tab3.page';
  import { ExploreContainerComponentModule } from '../explore-container/explore-container.module';
  import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      IonicModule,
      CommonModule,
      FormsModule,
      SwiperModule,
      ExploreContainerComponentModule,
      RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab3Page }])
    ],
    declarations: [Tab3Page],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
  })
  export class Tab3PageModule {}```
  ````

Comment: can you see any reference to `IonSlides` in code you've actually written? There's no reference in it to what you posted, so there's no obvious reason for the error from that

Comment: That's all the code involved. I used a swiper without the ionlide structure, but there was an error and it didn't work.

Comment: `swiper without the ionlide structure` perhaps that's the issue